# segmentation fault sigsegv stops under gdb

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, gdb, fortran, mpi

I'm working with a large simulation code that runs in parallel.  The user writes code to initialize a simulation and then the whole program runs.  I'm getting a seg fault (`SIGSEGV`) only when using more than 3 processors, and it ***doesn't happen when I run under gdb***.  I have rarely used gdb, or parallel codes in general.  How can I debug such a problem?  What kind of problem would stop happening when using gdb?

---

Details:

To use `gdb`, I did:

```
mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e gdb <PROGRAM>
```

then 4 xterms opened, and I said `run` in each one... the code executed normally.  Just running,

```
mpiexec -np 4 <PROGRAM>
```

and I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x113a1170d
#1  0x113a11c1b
#2  0x113edf5a9
#0  0x11122d70d
#1  0x11122dc1b
#2  0x1116d95a9
#3  0x10d1e9a44
#4  0x10d25c201
#5  0x10d1cb2ea
#6  0x10d1b3df4
#7  0x10d36e1f3
#3  0x10f9d4a44
#4  0x10fa47201
#5  0x10f9b62ea
#6  0x10f99edf4
#7  0x10fb591f3
```

I compiled with the Makefile's preset 'debug' options:

```
FFLAGS_DEBUG = -ggdb -c -O0 -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 \
-pedantic -Wall -Waliasing \
-Wsurprising -Wconversion -Wunderflow \
-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fbounds-check \
-fimplicit-none -fstack-protector-all
```

Comment: Try running under valgrind?

Comment: @PaulR I hadn't heard of this, downloading now.  Any quick tips for how/where to start?

Comment: For starters you can just do `valgrind <yourprogram> <yourags>` - it will run a bit slow, but if your program crashes then it should take you straight to the problem.

Comment: Note that when using mpirun, you need to do `mpirun -np 4 valgrind <yourprogram> ...`, although doing this initially in single processor without mpirun is probably a good starting point.  Note too that I've generally found valgrind a lot less useful for Fortran programs than C/C++.

Comment: Symptoms - like segfaults - of memory errors are often quite sensitive to perturbations in the run environment, so having it go away under gdb, while frustrating, isn't necessarily shocking.  In Fortran programs, the two most common types of memory errors in my experience are going out of bounds on array accesses and calls to external routines with wrong number/types of arguments.  You're already checking for array bounds with `-fbounds-check`, so my next suggestion would be to very closely investigate any library calls.

Comment: `--41054-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting`   
`--41054-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x700000D12000;  sp: 0x700000aa9ad8`
I assume it's just having trouble handling the `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: Are you able to use other compilers? I find testing code with `ifort`, `pgi`, `xlf`, `lahey` and `gfortran` can highlight different errors. As the different compilers trip up on different issues. Otherwise how large is the code? Are you able narrow down the scope? Lazy man's `print` statements can be helpful to get you towards the offending routine.

Comment: @TimothyBrown I'm trying to avoid other compilers (when I move from laptop to server, there is only 1 available), but that might be an option for debugging.  It is a massive code (100's of thousands of lines at least), but *very likely* the problem is with the relatively small amount of code that *i've written*... but it could be a subtle interaction between mine and theirs...

Comment: Another tool that might help, if you do not get more details in the traceback is the addr2line program, which should give you the line of code when the executable was compiled with debugging symbols.